# Why should we use WSDL4j for developing webservices?

Tags: web-services, wsdl4j

I need to develop Webservice Application for our Client .

I dont know anything about WSDL4J

From the net I found this

"The Web Services Description Language for Java Toolkit (WSDL4J) allows the creation, representation, and manipulation of WSDL documents. 
Is the reference implementation for JSR110 'JWSDL' (jcp.org)."

But anybody please tell me why should we use WSDL for developing webservices? 
Is there any specific advantage we will get?

And can anybody please point me a link where to start for working with WSDL4j?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You actually need not to use wsdl4j for developing web services or clients for web services. There are other SOAP stacks developed on top of that. Axis2 is such an open source SOAP stack..

WSDL2Java tool that comes with Axis2 - which been used to generate client side stubs from a given WSDL. uses wsdl4j internally..